# For Each String in List(of ClassWithIntegerAndString)?

Tags: .net, foreach

I have the following class:

```
Public Class TrainStation

    Public FileName As String
    Public StationName As String
    Public TrainID As eTrainID 'an enum

End Class
```

I have a list of this class:

```
Dim nList As new List(Of TrainStation)
'....
```

I would now like to go through each "StationName" preferrably like this:

```
For Each sStationName As String In nList.StationName

    If StrLen(sStationName) > 0 Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Is that possible? Preferrably without LINQ because I just don't get warm with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you loop through the list of stations and then check the property against the station. So the object will be a TrainStation instead of a string. Like so:

```
For Each station In nList

    If station.StationName.Length > 0 Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Actually, I can do this. It is pretty simple and straight forward. Actually, I can't see anything wrong with it. Thanks. :-)